# Compilation Issue with new Identity Framework 2.0 - Where is ApplicationUserManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have just installed the three NuGet packages for Identity 2.0:

```
◦Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework –Version 2.0.0
◦Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core -Version 2.0.0
◦Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.OWIN -Version 2.0.0
```

I am trying to implement Forgot Password functionality and this won't compile because it won't find ApplicationUserManager. How do I fix this?

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the file IdentityConfig.cs